# Why is the Jacobsen's catalyst with tert-Butyl groups a better catalyst for epoxidation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, catalysis

In an experiment I synthesised the below Jacobsen's catalst:

[image]

I used it to create styrene oxide through epoxidation. Chiral GC analysis showed that the enantiometric excess was lower compared to using Jacobsen's catalyst with tert-Butyl groups (shown below). This leads me to believe that it is more enantioselective, but why is this?

[image]

Comment: I haven't worked on this stuff in a more than a decade, but if memory serves, having more electron donating groups in the aryl ring increases selectivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of oxygen transfer reaction consists of a two step
catalytic cycle, wherein, first an intermediate (salen)$\ce{Mn^V}$ oxo complex is generated, and then the activated oxygen is added to the olefinic double bond.

Electron withdrawing and electron donating group influence the strength of the $\ce{Mn=O}$ bond, with electron withdrawing substituents leading to a weaker $\ce{Mn=O}$, and electron donating substituents leadings to a stronger $\ce{Mn=O}$ bond.

An argument based on Hammond Postulate can be applied where in the case of electron withdrawing substituents (weak $\ce{Mn=O}$ bond), one expects an early transition state, and in the case of electron donating substituents (stronger $\ce{Mn=O}$) a late transition state is seen.

Enantioselectivity is governed by interactions of the salen ligand, which in the transition state geometry adapts a folded geometry forming a chiral pocket, and the incoming olefin.

A late transition state demands a certain proximity between the
olefin and the manganese oxo complex. This leads to a less  spatial separation between substrate and catalyst and consequently allows for better differentiation of stereoisomeric transition structures.

Thus the attenuation of the reactivity of the oxo-species by electro donating groups, leading to a comparatively late transition state is the reason for higher enantioselectivity.

---

**References**

This article looks at the electronic effects of 5,5' substituents using DFT calculations.
[Cavallo, Luigi, and Heiko Jacobsen. "Electronic Effects in (salen)Mn-Based Epoxidation Catalysts." - The Journal of Organic Chemistry, 2008, 68(16), pp 6202–6207](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/jo034059a)

Comment: Also, it was posited that some types of reactions involved two salen complexes, which is why the oligomeric catalysts were developed: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040402014003779 (Yes, I'm the third author.) You can imagine that if this were the case, having t-butyl groups in the monomer would improve selectivity via steric factors...